# Is there a way to to pick a random agent in a rack system several times?

Tags: storage, anylogic

I want to create a storage system in which an AGV picks up a shelve from a rack system, take it to a working station, wait several seconds and then return it to the rack system. This works fine.
But after it was placed on the rack system again. The AGV should take a random shelve from the rack system and repeat the process. My problem is the simulation ends as soon as every shelve was taken to a working station. But I want to create a solution in which the shelve is picked several times and the order in which the shelves are picked up by the AGV is random. Currently there are picked up by the agv in order from left to right.

I realized I can change the Order in the queue function to FIFO and LIFO when I use LIFO the first row is selected first and then move to the last row.But I want to pick random shelves. I also tried using the wait Block instead of queue, but with this block nothing moved in my simulation. Additionally I select Restore Agent on Exit to make sure, that the shelve does not disappear, but the AGV still picks up one shelve one time and not several times

Currently my process looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQjNY.png)

Comment: no screen shown, pls add it. And clarify what you already tried to solve this, see some tips here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank You Benjamin for pointing this out. This is my first time asking a question, so thank you for helping to improve my asked question. I wish you a nice weekend and good luck with your consulting company.